# SCSS overlay display none is still displaying

Tags: html, css, sass, overlay

Working on a portfolio site while using SASS-

I want my project title to show up at the bottom of the image on hover.

I haven't tried the hover yet, but I would appreciate help with it if it's possible!

HTML:

```
<div class="projects">
      <div class="item">
      <img src="img/projects/project1.jpg" alt="Project">
      <div class="overlay">TRACKFIT</div>
      <a href="#!" class="btn-dark">
        <i class="fab fa-behance"></i>
      </a>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.projects {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.7rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

  img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px #fff solid;

    &.overlay {
      display: none;
    }

    &:hover {
      opactiy: 0.5;
      border-color: $secondary-color;
      @include easeOut;
    }
  }
}
```

[The "TRACKFIT" text it still displaying beneath the image, regardless of the overlay display:none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzSYD.png)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You select img with a class `overlay`, which doesn't exist in your HTML. You should remove `&` in front of `.overlay` and move it outside `img {}`

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/kendra_chu/19qte5rh/4/

```
.projects{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.7rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  .item{
     img{
          width: 100px;
          border: 3px #fff solid;   
          position: absolute
      }
       .title{
          display: none;
          position: relative /*text will appear on top of image*/
       }
      img:hover{
          opactiy: 0.5;
          border-color: #000;
      }
      img:hover + .title { /*display the tile when hover over the image*/
        display: block;
      }

  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="projects">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/290/?random" alt="Project">
        <div class="title">TITLE</div>
        <a href="#!" class="btn-dark">
          <i class="fab fa-behance"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Kendra :) I'm trying to get the text to appear on the image though, like an overlay on a low opacity black rectangle.

Comment: @BellaWella In that case, you can simply add `position: relative` to the `.title` class and `position: absolute` to the `img`, then you can modify its position however you want. The text will appear on top of the image on hover.

Comment: Ah ! Cool! However, now all my images are very very small and it looks like the structure of the text, bar, and image have been lost somewhere? Any ideas? Here's my current screen: http://tinypic.com/r/zxntac/9

Comment: I don't see your pic but my codes were a sample that is very similar to yours and I set the image to `100px` to test. Please modify it properly for your project.

Comment: That helped, but when I add position: absolute to the img, everything is huge - it looses the size constraints entirely. I've bene trying to work on it with your code for an hour and I don't know the problem!

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle link of what you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

You have an errant `&` selector before your `.overlay` in your SCSS. If you remove that, your code will at least hide the overlay.

Also consider closing the `<div id="projects">` tag in your HTML, it is still open.

You'd also likely want to target hovering the `.item` since the `.overlay` is a child of that and can be easily selected.

See codepen [here](https://codepen.io/t1mwillis/pen/PdXyBK).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `.item` in the relative position and the `.overlay` in the absolute position, after that you put it out off the visible space by moving it `100%`(which is exactly the height of their parent **`.item`** element) from top. and when you put you mouse hover the image, the `.overlay` is moved by modifing their margin negatively from top.

```
.project {
    .item {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        img {
            width: 100%;
            &:hover {
                & ~ .overlay {
                    margin-top: -100px;
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            transition: all 3s easy-in-out; // just to make it smoothly
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Do you know if it's possible to do something more like this https://www.idix.fr/references
I changed my css to mirror yours but the caption is actually no where near the image

Comment: Did it work like you want? https://jsfiddle.net/yvesdaxmaz/qo93mx7n/5/ here the red color is changing smoothly

Comment: Hey Yves! Almost ! How can I make it so the red goes over the entire image? You're amazing !

Comment: In the second link the red color cover the entire image